# How can I make a bot send a message in a Discord channel that only a certain user can see?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How can I send a message in a public Discord channel that only one user can see without just sending them a DM?

I currently have this:

```
client.on('message', async msg => {
    if (msg.content === '!onlineplayers') {
        await server.get();
        msg.reply(server.players.list.join(', ') || "There are no players online");
    }
})
```

But everyone can see the message it sends. How can I make it so that only the person who typed "!onlineplayers" can see the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by BLADEZ, the bot sends the message in a public textchannel. A solution might be to make the bot reply to the user through DM (Direct Message).

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never heard of a bot that is able to this, as it is sending a message inside a public discord. What you could do is set it so that after a bit the bot delete the message, to prevent a lot of bulk